# how to get current VAPI XP Test ID using VBScript?

Tags: vbscript, hp-quality-center

I have a piece of code in VB Script to add test parameters

```
Dim supportParamTest
Set supportParamTest = TDConnection.TestFactory.Item(1404)
Set testParamsFactory = supportParamTest.TestParameterFactory
Set parameter = testParamsFactory.AddItem(Null)
parameter.Name   ="Name"
parameter.Description = "desc"
parameter.Post
```

in line no : 2 TDConnection.TestFactory.Item(1404) here "1404" is hard coded
test id , i.e the above code will add test parameters to test id 1404 
Now i need to get the TestID of the current Test to make it generic

Can any one help me out?

Comment: Dim TestName
Dim supportTests
Set supportTests = TDConnection.TestFactory
Set Test = TestFactory.Fields
TestName = ID
TDOutput.Print(TestName)

Comment: above code will give the current test id, it works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim TestName 
Dim supportTests 
Set supportTests = TDConnection.TestFactory 
Set Test = TestFactory.Fields 
TestName = ID 
TDOutput.Print(TestName)
```

Successfully retrieves the current Test ID. It works !

Answer (score 1):

This is an old post, but in case anyone needs to know:
In a VAPI script, the global ID is available from the start.  No need to 'retrieve' anything.  So answer from Ganeshja works, but only because ID was already available.
The global variable ThisTest is available.  So for the above question, it would make more sense to use:
Set testParamsFactory = ThisTest.TestParameterFactory